# Watching for deleted files with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, delete-file, grunt-contrib-watch

Using grunt-watch to monitor for changes to files is great for add/change operations, because when it invokes the task with the change list the task's `files` (or `fileSrc`) property will contain the added/changed files.

Not so with deleted files. If you watch for deleted files, and invoke a task, the deleted file will not appear in the task's `filesSrc` property or the normalized portion of the `files` property.

Aside from manually normalizing the `orig` property of a particular `files` element, is there a way to force the deleted file to appear in `fileSrc` or the normalized part of `files`? If not, what's the best way to normalize `orig` (I don't want to reinvent the wheel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely the plugin is dumping the deleted files from the files array by design, the plugin however does emit a `watch` [event](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event) that you can listen for:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: ['**'],
    },
  },
});
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
  if (target === 'scripts' && action === 'deleted') {
    // your code goes here
  }
});
```

There's also ways to set up a watch task specific that runs a specific task for when the watcher detects a deletion.  Both methods are listed in the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).

Comment: Yeah I've used the technique described in "Compiling FIles as Needed". The trouble with the `watch` event is that there can only be one global `watch` listener, and if you have multiple watch targets running simultaneously it has no way to know which target a particular event is coming from.

Comment: For instance, if you take their example with jslint, and suppose you needed to run another watch target that did something much like jslint (call it jslint2) but on a separate (but overlapping) set of files, the watch listener would have no choice but to run both jslint and jslint2 for any file change in the union of the two sets (otherwise it may miss some files in one of the targets). But that means some files may get jslint'ed (or jslint2'ed) which shouldn't have been.

Comment: Change your conditional to check the target: `if (target === 'jslint' && action === 'deleted')`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Can you add that as part of your answer, and I'll accept it from there?